# How do I add quotes to each object in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm comparing the ID values of two different arrays, but one of the arrays has quotes around each number and the other does not. How do I add quotes to each of the IDs in the array below? e.g. "268056199934590"

```
Object.all.collect { |f| f["f_id"] }
[268056199934590, 306589562725323, 223636134385969]
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Assuming you know it's numbers we're talking about, why not convert strings to int? Something like `collect {|f| f["f_id"].to_i }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Not having quotes" means they are number, that you are comparing to strings. So you have a choice here : convert your string to integer using `"123".to_i`, or the other way around with `123.to_s`

Comment: wow i was not thinking, thanks for knocking some sense into me haha